# Converting different date format in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file which contains dates in different formats, there are also some strings within the content, for example:

```
5/10/2013,
03-06-2013,
4156200%,
Friday, May 10, 2013
```

I want to be able to check if a given string is a date, then give it this format: `Month-Day-Year`. In the example content above there are 3 dates: `5/10/2013`, `3-06-2013` and `Friday, May 10, 2013` I need a function which receives those strings and converts them into a date, with the format specified before if needed.

If a string is not a valid date then I want to keep the same content in its place.

Below there's an example of what I believe the function would look like:

```
convert_date($st_val){
   $ret = '';

   if( isFomatDate( $st_val ) ) {
      $ret = fomatDate( $st_val, mm-dd-yyyy );
   } else {
      $ret = $val_val;
   }
}
```

The expected output for this function should be something like:

```
// Entered string
5/10/2013
// Expected output
05-10-2013
// Entered string
03-06-2013
// Expected output
03-06-2013
// Entered string
4156200%
// Expected output
4156200%
// Entered String
aaaa
// Expected output
aaaa
// Entered string
Friday, May 10, 2013
// Expected output
05-11-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` function if it is not a date format it returns false . If it returned false return the original string .

```
$time = strtotime($string);
if(!$time)
{
   return $string;
}
return $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below function:

```
function dates_format($datesstr)
{
$dates_str=strtotime($datesstr);

if($dates_str!="")
{
return date("d-m-Y"); 
}
else
{
return $datesstr;
}

}

echo dates_format("12-10-2013");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert_date($st_val){
 $ret = '';
 $check = strtotime($st_val);
 if($check){
  $ret = date("m-d-Y",$check);
 }else{
   $ret = $st_val;
 }
 return $ret;
}

echo convert_date('5/10/2013')."<br>";
echo convert_date('03-06-2013')."<br>";
echo convert_date('4156200%')."<br>";
echo convert_date('aaaa')."<br>";
echo convert_date('Friday, May 11, 2013')."<br>";
```